# How to prove $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $f(a^k)=k$ is bijective?

Tags: group-isomorphism

The following isomorphism

$f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $f(a^k)=k$

is involved in the proof of the theorem

> Let $G$ be cyclic, $|G|= \infty$, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

However,

my source does not show, why $f$ is bijective.

How is this seen?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is an isomorphism, then it *must* be a bijection (why?).

Comment: There's a slight variation of the proof in: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Cyclic_Group_is_Isomorphic_to_Integers#Proof. It uses the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$, $f(k)=a^k$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $|<a>|$ (order of group generated by $a$) is infinite. Then, define $f$ as in your post, then $f(a)=1$, $f(e)=0$ (where $e$ is the identity in $<a>$) and $f(a^{-1})=-1$. Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, and compare its behavior with that of $<a>$, what can you conclude?